# What's the meaning of `A verification email will be sent to the abuse address of the Domain`?

Tags: email, domain

What's the meaning of `A verification email will be sent to the abuse address of the Domain`?

> A verification email will be sent to the abuse address of the Domain you enter above. You must accept this email. It will contain a 5-digit token you must enter at Step 3. The Main Domain must be identified in network records for your IP Ranges.

[image: Screenshot of warning notice]

I don't know how can a email can be sent to a domain?
What's this mean? What should I fill there?

Surely it doesn't mean that there should be a email address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know how can a email can be sent to a domain?

The message *doesn't say* that the email will be sent to a domain. It says the message will be sent to the 'abuse' address *of* that domain. For example, if the domain is `example.com` then usally the actual mailbox address will be `abuse@example.com`.

So there *is* an email address, but it will be automatically determined by Spamhaus:

- the 'local' part (prefix) is always `abuse@`;
- the 'domain' part is determined based on what company owns the IP address.

Generally, you should not fill this form at all unless you work for the ISP or the hosting company (in other words, unless the address you're trying to remove belongs to your own ASN).

Comment: I am doubt about why the Main Domain use the `www.()`? why now directory use `mail.()`, or `()`?

Comment: Most ISPs have a company website on their main "brand" domain. So Spamhaus are _probably_ just providing `www` as an example, so that the person filling the form will understand that they need to specify the company's main domain, the one that's used for their web and branding and everything.